# Map C++ lambda function with capture list to a function parameter

Tags: c++11, lambda

I have a C++ function that takes another function as a parameter. When I use this function I pass it a lambda function with a capture list. This works fine until I attempt to add items to the capture list. When I do it says it can't convert the lambda to the same syntax as the function (hopefully that made sense).

**Function Declaration:**

```
SYMCXRESULT Configure(MyManager *manager, void (*completionHandler)(MyResponse * response)) noexcept;
```

**Lambda Call:**

```
Configure(manager, [=](MyResponse * response) -> void {
            object->functionCall();
        });
```

**Error Message:**

```
No viable conversion from '(lambda at /path/file.mm:370:67)' to 'void (*)(MyResponse *__strong)'
```

Comment: A captureless lambda is convertible to a plain function pointer. A lambda with captures is not - there's not enough space in the function pointer's worth of bits to store the captured values.

Answer (score 0):

As @Igor mentions, you can't pass a lambda with captures to a C-style function pointer. If you are indeed using C++11, you should use an R-value reference:

```
template <typename lambda>
SYMCXRESULT Configure(MyManager *manager, lambda &&func) noexcept;
// func();
```